# How to remove date in Recent Post widget?

Tags: widgets

I am stuck with this. I open the file default_widget.php inside wp-icludes folder, i want to remove the date displayed by the default recent post widget. I cannot find it! Pls help!!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first of all **never** change any of the core files. It will cause issues with updating WordPress. Secondly, there is no date shown in the default Recent Posts widget supplied with WordPress 3.2.

What version of WordPress are you using? Are you sure it's the default WordPress Recent Posts widget?